# Change span on click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```js
 $('a').click(function() {
  $('a span').first().addClass('hide');
   $('a span:nth-child(2)').removeClass('hide');
                $('a span:nth-child(2)').addClass('display');
 });
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
 }

.display {
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <br>
  <span class="hide">World</span>
</a>
```

When I click on the link I want the first span hide and the 2nd span appears.

I want to do it multiple times (click on this link multiples times and have the same result).

I try to do it with this Jquery code

Comment: please clarify your question, what is your exact problem ?

Comment: When I click on the link I want the first span hide then the 2nd span appears.

Comment: How do you do it multiple times? Once one element is hidden and the other visible, you can't really do it again without reversing that, is that what you mean, a toggle functionality.

Comment: Yes a toggle functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just toggle the classes
and you have to prevent the default on the link so it doesn't try to leave the page.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a span').toggleClass('hide show');
});
```

here is a [work demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9raqpa9/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Loop through the children of the `a` and swap their classes. Doing this method allows you to do other things as well as just toggle the class like adding text/css attributes to the `span`'s.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(index, element)
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass('hide'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
            $(this).addClass('display');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('display');
            $(this).addClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcd84jnn/) of the code above

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for:

HTML:

```
<a class='hide-clicker' href="#">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span class="hide">World</span>
</a>
```

jquery:

```
$("a.hide-clicker").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```